# SQL Query with conditional order by for a specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is how my data looks like

```
CompanyName   |    CompanyCode
-----------        -----------
                   B190  
ARBOT              B213 
INFRA              A946
MichalesTest       B207
MyCompany          Alerf
MyCompany          lerf
SNELSY             A857
SNELSY             A954
```

I want to sort the list with `CompanyName = 'MyCompany'` to be the first in the list with its associated `CompanyCode` sorted in ASC.

And all other items to be listed after `'MyCompany'` with its `CompanyName` sorted in ASC. Entries with null `CompanyName` can be at the end of the list.

I’ve tried so far with the below query but I didn’t get the expected result. I was following the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx#Case)

```
SELECT [CompanyName], [CompanyCode] FROM  [dbo].COND_ORDERBY_TEST
    ORDER BY CASE CompanyName WHEN 'MyCompany' THEN CompanyName
    ELSE CompanyName END, CompanyCode
```

I expect my final result set like the below

```
CompanyName   |    CompanyCode
-----------        -----------
MyCompany           Alerf     
MyCompany           lerf      
ARBOT               B213  
INFRA               A946   
MichalesTest        B207 
SNELSY              A857
SNELSY              A954 
                    B190
```

I’m sure there should be an elegant way to do this but I'm not getting it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don think so it's duplicate @andyp... The solution of the linked question does not apply on this question in my opinion.

Comment: You final result set does not match your requirements -- items after MyCompany are not sorted by company code.  I went by the requirements in my answer.

Comment: Good catch @Hogan, that was a typo, I edited the post. I really wanted them to be sorted by CompanyName after MyCompany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I face this kind of situation, I generally do this:

```
SELECT [CompanyName]
     , [CompanyCode]
     , SortOrder = case when CompanyName is null then 3
                        when CompanyName = 'MyCompany' then 1
                        else 2
                    end
  FROM [dbo].COND_ORDERBY_TEST
 ORDER BY 3 asc, CompanyName asc
```

As you are always ordering by the same field, SQL Server will not guess what order do you want...

Try it :)

Comment: Consider an `else` clause instead of another `when`...

Comment: Yeah it could be... I like this way. I think it's clear to understand what order I want... thanks for the sugestion :)

Comment: The advantage of WHEN here is that you will not be caught out with imputing a result for an unexpected value. The disadvantage is that if you do come across an unexpected value the CASE will evaluate to NULL which may cause unexpected problems. So you just need to decide which type of unexpected problem you want. The best is to use WHEN for every expected value and still have an ELSE that results in some strange obvious value like -100000

Comment: It's quite readable. This satisfies 90% of what I wanted except that it didn't sort other companynames in ASC. I slightly modified your code as "ORDER BY 3 asc, [CompanyName] ASC"

Comment: Ok, followed some sugestions, It's better now :) thanks!

Comment: What I wanted, thanks. Your edit includes @ErikE suggestion too.

Comment: @Kevin what unexpected value could there be, here? `WHEN X IS NULL ... WHEN X = 'value' ... ELSE`? Reasoning about this is easily done by anyone with very, very basic knowledge of SQL. The new version with an `ELSE` clause **and** `WHEN != THEN 2` makes it appear that the writer of the SQL is a highly ignorant raw beginner. Think of it this way: if you want to change which company is listed first, why would you make yourself edit it in two places? That is *more likely* to lead to an error--if only one line got changed. Use `ELSE` to terminate the list, period.

Comment: @ErikE: you're completely correct: I wasn't reading the conditions closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column in the select to solve this problem and then sort using that column

```
SELECT [CompanyName], [CompanyCode], 
(CASE WHEN COMPANYNAME='MyCompany' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS SortCol
FROM  [dbo].COND_ORDERBY_TEST
ORDER BY SortCol, CompanyName, CompanyCode
```

Comment: Why would you do `THEN 1 ELSE 0` only to reverse it with `DESC` instead of just `THEN 0 ELSE 1`? And why would you pollute the result set with an extra unwanted/unneeded column?

Comment: Good point. I updated it.

Comment: This brings up 'MyCompany' in the top of the list with the 'CompanyCode' sorted in ASC but the other CompanyName are not sorted ASC.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Do you want the companies after 'MyCompany' to be sorted by CompanyName or CompanyCode?

Comment: I want them to be sorted by CompanyName.

Comment: I updated the answer. It's just a matter of sorting by CompanyName before CompanyCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CompanyName = 'MyCompany' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CompanyName, CompanyCode
```

Comment: This is useful too except that it brings the companyname with 'null' value as the first item after 'MyCompany' rather I want it at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
      with temp as
        (
       SELECT CompanyName, CompanyCode, 
      CASE WHEN COMPANYNAME='MyCompany' THEN '0' ELSE CompanyName END AS tempcol
      FROM  table name order by CompanyName
      )
      select CompanyName, CompanyCode from temp order by tempcol asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT [CompanyName], [CompanyCode]
  FROM (
    SELECT [CompanyName], [CompanyCode],
         CASE WHEN CompanyName = 'MyCompany' THEN 1
              WHEN CompanyName is null THEN 3
              ELSE 2 END as orderer
    FROM [dbo].COND_ORDERBY_TEST
  ) T
  ORDER BY orderer ASC, CompanyName ASC
```

Comment: Looks promising but I get 'Incorrect syntax' error when I replace 'T' in your code with my actual table name. Any idea?

Comment: you should not change t.  I had a typo, fixed.  Give this a try, it might be faster depending on the data model you are using.

Comment: yes, it works perfect now.